# Set an index page for a specific folder in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

What I want to do should be quite simple: when the admin writes `www.example.com/admin` I want that he's addressed to `www.example.com/admin/admin_index.php`.

I wrote this rule and I checked on other posts here on Stackoverflow: it apparently seems to be correct, but it actually doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteRule     ^/admin/?$ /admin/admin_index.php [L,NC]
```

Has anyone any clue on why the redirect doesn't work, since it "stays" at `www.example.com/admin` outputting (obviously) the `403` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a rewrite rule. Just use `DirectoryIndex` directive in `admin/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex admin_index.php
```

This will load `admin/admin_index.php` when a request comes for `http://domain.com/admin/`